# How to access $(this) div in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to change the background of `div` that `is clicked`. So, how i can access `$(this)` div in angular?

My code is:

```
<div id="single" ng-click="changeit()"> 
     foobar
</div>
```

And function is:

```
$scope.changeit=function($scope){
    // jquery code $(this).css({"background":"#A4A4A4"});
    // how in angular ?
}
```

Comment: use this may be it work  ng-click="changeit($event)"

Comment: and why you accespt $scope in parameter ?

Comment: Why not use a directive like ng-style or ng-class for this task rather than calling a function on your scope and manipulating DOM in your controller, which is not a best practice in Angular.

Comment: sorry thats mistake @uzaif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `$event` and use `target` to retrieve the current clicked element.

```
<div id="single" ng-click="changeit($event)"> 
    asad
</div>

$scope.changeit = function ($event) {
    $($event.target).css({ 'background': '#A4A4A4' });
}
```

Using a directive way, you could do it like this :

```
<div id="single" data-change-color>foobar</div>
```

And the `changeColor` directive which adds a `click` event on the element and changes the color when clicking on it.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModuleName')
        .directive('changeColor', changeColor);

    changeColor.$inject = [];

    function changeColor () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: link
        };

        function link (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', onClick(element));
        }

        function onClick (element) {
            return function () {
                element.css({ 'background': '#A4A4A4' });
            }
        }
    }
}) ();
```

Comment: What is the reason you would solve this problem in such a manner rather than using directives?

Comment: Im new in angular i dnt know about this

Comment: jst want to change background color on click event .

Comment: can you help me how it can be done using directive ?

Comment: @Asad Sheikh , I added an example code using a directive

Comment: you write data-change-color in div tag and didn't use it in whole directive

Comment: I didn't understand it can you elaborate please . @MikeVranckx

Comment: The `data-change-color` attribute initializes the `changeColor` directive which handles the rest. AngularJs automatically removes the `data-` prefix and transforms it to camelCase (by removing the hyphens). `data-change-color` -> `changeColor` (which is the name of the directive)

Comment: @MikeVranckx any reason to use $(this) instead of element ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker, there is no particular reason for that. I'll update my answer with `element` usage

Answer (score 3):

DOM manipulation should ideally be the sole domain of directives when using angular. This keeps us from gluing our controller logic into our DOM presentation which makes for a horrible mess. With this in mind Angular has two directives related to styling, ng-style and ng-class. Ng-class is demonstrated below.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <style>
      .active{
        background:red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    
    <button ng-click="activeButton = 1" ng-class="{'active' :activeButton==1}">Button 1</button>
    <button ng-click="activeButton =2" ng-class="{'active' :activeButton==2}">Button 2</button>
    <button ng-click="activeButton = 3" ng-class="{'active' :activeButton==3}">Button 3</button>
    
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("app",[]);
      app.controller("ctrl",function(){});
      angular.bootstrap(document,[app.name]);
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```